# Cosmos DB- The document body must be an object or a string representing a JSON-serialized object

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, java-11, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to store items in cosmos DB using stored procedure . I am following below documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=java-sdk and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#create-an-item

Still I am getting below Error

```
{"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: The document body must be an object or a string representing a JSON-serialized object.\r\nStack trace: Error: The document body must be an object or a string representing a JSON-serialized object.\n   at createDocument (script.js:644:21)\n   at tryCreate (script.js:20:9)\n   at createToDoItems (script.js:15:5)\n   at __docDbMain (script.js:37:5)\n   at Global code (script.js:1:2)"]},"statusCode":400,"subStatusCode":400,"isGone":false,"isNotFound":false,"isInvalidPartition":false,"isThroughputControlRequestRateTooLarge":false,"requestCharge":3.45,"itemLSN":-1,"sessionToken":"0:-1#244878","backendLatencyInMs":2.457,"exceptionMessage":"[\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: The document body must be an object or a string representing a JSON-serialized object.\\r\\nStack trace: Error: The document body must be an object or a string representing a JSON-serialized object.\\n   at createDocument (script.js:644:21)\\n   at tryCreate (script.js:20:9)\\n   at createToDoItems (script.js:15:5)\\n   at __docDbMain (script.js:37:5)\\n   at Global code (script.js:1:2)\"]"
```

Java Code :

```
List<ChargeTransaction> chargeTransactionList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ChargeTransaction chargeTransaction :
    getChargeTransactions(event, chargeTransactionList)) {
    list.add(chargeTransaction);
}
 CosmosStoredProcedureProperties definition;
try {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("createEvent.js");
    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    definition = new CosmosStoredProcedureProperties(
            "spCreateEvent",
            result
        );
    CosmosStoredProcedureResponse response = container
            .getScripts()
            .createStoredProcedure(definition);
CosmosStoredProcedure sproc = container   
        .getScripts()
        .getStoredProcedure("spCreateEvent");

CosmosStoredProcedureRequestOptions options = new CosmosStoredProcedureRequestOptions();
options.setPartitionKey(
    new PartitionKey(event.getEventPayload().getOriginOrderNo())
);

CosmosStoredProcedureResponse response = sproc.execute(
        list,
    options
);
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  }catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

createEvent.js

```
function createToDoItems(items) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var count = 0;

if (!items) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var numItems = items.length;

if (numItems == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    return;
}

tryCreate(items[count], callback);

function tryCreate(item, callback) {
    var options = { disableAutomaticIdGeneration: false };

    var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, item, options, callback);

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}

function callback(err, item, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
    count++;
    if (count >= numItems) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {
        tryCreate(items[count], callback);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: spCreateEvent.js ?

Comment: thanks for pointing out . Corrected that but still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Complex types will be passed into the stored proc as a string. You can coerce `items` to an object or array by using `var parsedItems = JSON.parse(items);`

Comment: but in their official doc they are passing list as it is and also execute function is expecting argument as List<Object> and not a String

Comment: Object ct = list.toArray(); and then passing Arrays.asList(ct) as input solves my issue.

Comment: @loren ah, that sounds a bit different to how the .Net SDK does it. A bit strange that they differ, makes consuming the same SP from different clients a bit more painful.

Comment: This is the documentation covering arrays being passed as stringified JSON: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#arrays-as-input-parameters-for-stored-procedures